# Focus on predicting top n values

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

Assume a dataset of size $(m,p)$ where $m$ is the number of rows and $p$ is the number of columns. $m$ is a continuous set of independent variables. The dependent variable is continuous with fat tails.

Let, $y : (m,1)$ be the continuous (regression) variable I need to predict. But my final use case is only on the top $n$ values of predicted $\hat{y}$ i.e $J = (\Sigma_{ i = 1}^{n} \hat{y_{i}})/n $ where I know $n$ beforehand, meaning that while other values of $y$ will be helpful in supervised prediction because they are of the same functional form, I only have use of the top $n$ predicted values.

Also, I have a feature $x_{imp}$ among the $p$-length feature set that is a very good gauge of ranking of $y$. Meaning that if I sort the dataset by  $x_{imp}$ and select the top $n$ rows, there is a high probability that top $n$ rows of $\hat{y}$ would be a subset of these, if not completely the same.

How should I go about building a machine learning model for this specific use case, preferably using a deep neural network?

Comment: A CART seems better for this case IMO. ANNs are not the best models for everything, beware of that.

Comment: Can you explicitely clarify the question with respect to what m (observations/datapoints?) and what n (probabilities? predictions?) stands for.

Comment: @hH1sG0n3 I have edited the question. n is just a arbitrary portion of the tail distribution I need to capture (e.g top 10 values)